# Proxy with express.js

Tags: node.js, proxy, express, reverse-proxy

To avoid same-domain AJAX issues, I want my node.js web server to forward all requests from URL `/api/BLABLA` to another server, for example `other_domain.com:3000/BLABLA`, and return to user the same thing that this remote server returned, transparently.

All other URLs (beside `/api/*`) are to be served directly, no proxying.

How do I achieve this with node.js + express.js? Can you give a simple code example?

(both the web server and the remote `3000` server are under my control, both running node.js with express.js)

---

So far I found this https://github.com/http-party/node-http-proxy , but reading the documentation there didn't make me any wiser. I ended up with

```
var proxy = new httpProxy.RoutingProxy();
app.all("/api/*", function(req, res) {
    console.log("old request url " + req.url)
    req.url = '/' + req.url.split('/').slice(2).join('/'); // remove the '/api' part
    console.log("new request url " + req.url)
    proxy.proxyRequest(req, res, {
        host: "other_domain.com",
        port: 3000
    });
});
```

but nothing is returned to the original web server (or to the end user), so no luck.

Comment: the way you do it is working for me, without any modifications

Comment: Although a bit too late to answer, but was facing similar issue and resolved it by removing body parser so that request body is not being parsed before proxying it further.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You want to use [`http.request`](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback) to create a similar request to the remote API and return its response.

Something like this:

```js
const http = require('http');
// or use import http from 'http';


/* your app config here */

app.post('/api/BLABLA', (oreq, ores) => {
  const options = {
    // host to forward to
    host: 'www.google.com',
    // port to forward to
    port: 80,
    // path to forward to
    path: '/api/BLABLA',
    // request method
    method: 'POST',
    // headers to send
    headers: oreq.headers,
  };

  const creq = http
    .request(options, pres => {
      // set encoding
      pres.setEncoding('utf8');

      // set http status code based on proxied response
      ores.writeHead(pres.statusCode);

      // wait for data
      pres.on('data', chunk => {
        ores.write(chunk);
      });

      pres.on('close', () => {
        // closed, let's end client request as well
        ores.end();
      });

      pres.on('end', () => {
        // finished, let's finish client request as well
        ores.end();
      });
    })
    .on('error', e => {
      // we got an error
      console.log(e.message);
      try {
        // attempt to set error message and http status
        ores.writeHead(500);
        ores.write(e.message);
      } catch (e) {
        // ignore
      }
      ores.end();
    });

  creq.end();
});
```

*Notice: I haven't really tried the above, so it might contain parse errors hopefully this will give you a hint as to how to get it to work.*

Comment: Yeah, some modifications were necessary, but I like this better than introducing an extra new "Proxy" module dependency. A bit verbose, but at least I know exactly what's going on. Cheers.

Comment: It seems like you need to do res.writeHead before data chink is written, otherwise you'll get error (headers cant be written after body).

Comment: @user124114 - please put the full solution that you have used

Comment: seems that you'll have problem setting headers this way. `Cannot render headers after they are sent to the client`

Comment: replace it like this:
```var preparedWrite = '';

    // wait for data
    cres.on('data', function(chunk){
      //res.write(chunk);
   preparedWrite = preparedWrite+chunk;
    });

    cres.on('close', function(){
      // closed, let's end client request as well 
      res.writeHead(cres.statusCode);
      res.end();
    }); 

    cres.on('end', function(){
      // finished, let's finish client request as well 
      res.writeHead(cres.statusCode);
   res.write(preparedWrite);
      res.end();
    });
```

Comment: I've updated the answer to es6 syntax and fixed the writeHead issue

Answer (score 243):

Note that [request](https://github.com/request/request/) has been deprecated as of February 2020, so I'll leave the answer below for historical reasons, but please consider moving to an alternative listed in this [issue](https://github.com/request/request/issues/3143), moving to the natively built-in Fetch API (as of Node 18), or using [express-http-proxy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-http-proxy).

#### Original answer

I did something similar but I used [request](https://github.com/mikeal/request) instead:

```
var request = require('request');
app.get('/', function(req,res) {
  //modify the url in any way you want
  var newurl = 'http://google.com/';
  request(newurl).pipe(res);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, much simpler than using Node.js' HTTP request

Comment: Even simpler, if you also pipe the request:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7559862/proxy-with-nodejs-and-express/20539239#20539239

Comment: Nice and clean solution. I posted an answer to make it work with POST request also (otherwise it doesn't forward your post body to the API). If you edit your answer I'd be happy to remove mine.

Comment: Also see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20198377/132208) for improved error handling.

Comment: whenever I try to do similar routing (or the exact same) I end up with the following:
stream.js:94
      throw er; // Unhandled stream error in pipe.
            ^
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND google.com
    at errnoException (dns.js:44:10)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:94:26)

any ideas?

Comment: Can you pass the IP address through this somehow?

Comment: Doesn't seem to work anymore with `request`. Throws a `write after end` error.

Comment: What does `pipe()` do here? does it return the complete response get from the remote service?

Comment: @Jonathan @trigoman now that `request` has been deprecated (see notice at https://github.com/request/request), what is the alternative?

Comment: Hi, what if I need to alter a string on the HTML body before piping out to the client?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66991063/3965) answer helped me with a non-deprecated solution using `node-fetch`.

Answer (score 142):

I found a shorter and very straightforward solution which works seamlessly, and with authentication as well, using [express-http-proxy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-http-proxy):

```
const url = require('url');
const proxy = require('express-http-proxy');

// New hostname+path as specified by question:
const apiProxy = proxy('other_domain.com:3000/BLABLA', {
    proxyReqPathResolver: req => url.parse(req.baseUrl).path
});
```

And then simply:

```
app.use('/api/*', apiProxy);
```

Note: as mentioned by @MaxPRafferty, use `req.originalUrl` in place of `baseUrl` to preserve the querystring:

```
    forwardPath: req => url.parse(req.baseUrl).path
```

Update: As mentioned by Andrew (thank you!), there's a ready-made solution using the same principle:

```
npm i --save http-proxy-middleware
```

And then:

```
const proxy = require('http-proxy-middleware')
var apiProxy = proxy('/api', {target: 'http://www.example.org/api'});
app.use(apiProxy)
```

Documentation: [http-proxy-middleware on Github](https://github.com/chimurai/http-proxy-middleware)

Comment: The req.url doesn't have the full url, so updated the answer to use req.baseUrl instead of req.url

Comment: I also like to use req.originalUrl in place of baseUrl to preserve querystrings, but this may not always be the desired behavior.

Comment: @MaxPRafferty - vaid comment. Worth noting. Thanks.

Comment: This is the best solution. I'm using http-proxy-middleware, but it's the same concept. Don't spin your own proxy solution when there are great ones out there already.

Comment: there's another package that is more simple to use 
npm install express-proxy-server --save
var proxy = require('express-proxy-server');
app.use('/proxy', proxy('http://www.example.org/api'));

Comment: `http-proxy-middleware/dist/index.js' does not provide an export named 'default`

Comment: This resolved my issue. The only difference was the version of http-proxy-middleware that I installed did things slightly different which was easy to figure out following documentations.

Comment: This helped me but I had to change forwardPath to proxyReqPathResolver. It looks like they deprecated forwardPath.

Comment: http-proxy-middleware depends on http-proxy package. The http-proxy has memory leaks when client closes connection prematurely. You can follow the issue here https://github.com/chimurai/http-proxy-middleware/issues/782

Comment: @AmirSaleem thanks for the info!
This answer is 7 years old - if there are any alternatives nowadays, I'd be happy to update it.

Answer (score 53):

To extend [trigoman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/358059/trigoman)'s answer (full credits to him) to work with POST (could also make work with PUT etc):

```
app.use('/api', function(req, res) {
  var url = 'YOUR_API_BASE_URL'+ req.url;
  var r = null;
  if(req.method === 'POST') {
     r = request.post({uri: url, json: req.body});
  } else {
     r = request(url);
  }

  req.pipe(r).pipe(res);
});
```

Comment: Couldn't make it work with PUT. But works great for GET and POST. Thank you!!

Comment: @Protron for PUT requests just use something like `if(req.method === 'PUT'){ r = request.put({uri: url, json: req.body}); }`

Comment: If you need to pass through headers as part of a PUT or POST request, make sure to delete the content-length header so request can calculate it. Otherwise, the receiving server could truncate the data, which will lead to an error.

Comment: @Henrik Peinar, will this help when i do a login post request and expect to redirect from web.com/api/login to web.com/

Answer (score 30):

I used the following setup to direct everything on `/rest` to my backend server (on port 8080), and all other requests to the frontend server (a webpack server on port 3001). It supports all HTTP-methods, doesn't lose any request meta-info and supports websockets (which I need for hot reloading)

```
var express  = require('express');
var app      = express();
var httpProxy = require('http-proxy');
var apiProxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer();
var backend = 'http://localhost:8080',
    frontend = 'http://localhost:3001';

app.all("/rest/*", function(req, res) {
  apiProxy.web(req, res, {target: backend});
});

app.all("/*", function(req, res) {
    apiProxy.web(req, res, {target: frontend});
});

var server = require('http').createServer(app);
server.on('upgrade', function (req, socket, head) {
  apiProxy.ws(req, socket, head, {target: frontend});
});
server.listen(3000);
```

Comment: This is the only one that also deals with web-sockets.

Answer (score 21):

First install express and http-proxy-middleware

```
npm install express http-proxy-middleware --save
```

Then in your server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const proxy = require('http-proxy-middleware');

const app = express();
app.use(express.static('client'));

// Add middleware for http proxying 
const apiProxy = proxy('/api', { target: 'http://localhost:8080' });
app.use('/api', apiProxy);

// Render your site
const renderIndex = (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'client/index.html'));
}
app.get('/*', renderIndex);

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('Listening on: http://localhost:3000');
});
```

In this example we serve the site on port 3000, but when a request end with /api we redirect it to localhost:8080.

http://localhost:3000/api/login redirect to http://localhost:8080/api/login

Comment: Look here for how to use the new version of `http-proxy-middleware` https://stackoverflow.com/a/60755865

Answer (score 7):

Ok, here's a ready-to-copy-paste answer using the require('request') npm module and an environment variable *instead of an hardcoded proxy):

coffeescript

```
app.use (req, res, next) ->                                                 
  r = false
  method = req.method.toLowerCase().replace(/delete/, 'del')
  switch method
    when 'get', 'post', 'del', 'put'
      r = request[method](
        uri: process.env.PROXY_URL + req.url
        json: req.body)
    else
      return res.send('invalid method')
  req.pipe(r).pipe res
```

javascript:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var method, r;
  method = req.method.toLowerCase().replace(/delete/,"del");
  switch (method) {
    case "get":
    case "post":
    case "del":
    case "put":
      r = request[method]({
        uri: process.env.PROXY_URL + req.url,
        json: req.body
      });
      break;
    default:
      return res.send("invalid method");
  }
  return req.pipe(r).pipe(res);
});
```

Comment: Rather than a case statement all of which do the same thing except use a different request function) you could sanitize first (e.g. an if statement that calls your default if the method isn't in the list of approved methods), and then just do r = request[method](/*  the rest */);

Answer (score 4):

I found a shorter solution that does exactly what I want https://github.com/http-party/node-http-proxy

After installing `http-proxy`

```
npm install http-proxy --save
```

Use it like below in your server/index/app.js

```
var proxyServer = require('http-route-proxy');
app.use('/api/BLABLA/', proxyServer.connect({
  to: 'other_domain.com:3000/BLABLA',
  https: true,
  route: ['/']
}));
```

I really have spent days looking everywhere to avoid this issue, tried plenty of solutions and none of them worked but this one.

Hope it is going to help someone else too :)

Answer (score 2):

I don't have have an express sample, but one with plain `http-proxy` package. A very strip down version of the proxy I used for my blog.

In short, all nodejs http proxy packages work at the http protocol level, not tcp(socket) level. This is also true for express and all express middleware. None of them can do transparent proxy, nor NAT, which means keeping incoming traffic source IP in the packet sent to backend web server.

However, web server can pickup original IP from http x-forwarded headers and add it into the log.

The `xfwd: true` in `proxyOption` enable x-forward header feature for `http-proxy`.

```
const url = require('url');
const proxy = require('http-proxy');

proxyConfig = {
    httpPort: 8888,
    proxyOptions: {
        target: {
            host: 'example.com',
            port: 80
        },
        xfwd: true // <--- This is what you are looking for.
    }
};

function startProxy() {

    proxy
        .createServer(proxyConfig.proxyOptions)
        .listen(proxyConfig.httpPort, '0.0.0.0');

}

startProxy();
```

Reference for X-Forwarded Header: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For

Full version of my proxy: https://github.com/J-Siu/ghost-https-nodejs-proxy

Answer (score 1):

I figure out a way to have more control on the proxy request.

Using axios, the response of request made by proxy server is pipelined to the client in the form of stream.

More header and data body controls can be conducted by client to pass more information through proxy server.

```js
// proxy.js

import { Router } from "express";
var router = Router();
import axios from "axios";

// Proxy the request
router.all("/", async function (req, res, next) {
  let url = req.body["url"];
  let method = req.body["method"] ? req.body["method"] : "GET";
  let headers = req.body["headers"] ? req.body["headers"] : null;
  let params = req.body["params"] ? req.body["params"] : null;
  let data = req.body["data"] ? req.body["data"] : null;

  const response = await axios({
    method: method,
    url: url,
    headers: headers,
    params: params,
    data: data,
    responseType: "stream",
  });

  // Set the header of response as the header of the proxy response
  for (let key in response.headers) {
    res.setHeader(key, response.headers[key]);
  }

  // Pipe the response to the client
  const stream = response.data;
  stream.pipe(res);
});

export default router;
```

```js
// client.js

fetch("http://localhost:3000/proxy", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        url: picURL,
        method: "GET",
        headers: { Host: "wx2.sinaimg.cn" },
      }),
    }).then(async (res) => {
      const blobURL = URL.createObjectURL(await res.blob());
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

For Node 18+, you can use the native Fetch API:

```
import bodyParser from 'body-parser'

const pathsToProxy = /\/users/
const proxyApiUrl = 'https://yourapiproxy.com/users'

app.all(pathsToProxy, bodyParser.json(), (req, res) => {
    const url = req.url.replace(pathsToProxy, proxyApiUrl);
    
    fetch(url, {
        method: req.method,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': req.headers['content-type'],
        },
        body: ['PUT', 'POST'].includes(req.method) ? JSON.stringify(req.body) : undefined
    }).then(response => {
        response.body.pipeTo(
            new WritableStream({
                start() {
                    res.statusCode = response.status;
                    response.headers.forEach((v, n) => res.setHeader(n, v));
                },
                write(chunk) {
                    res.write(chunk);
                },
                close() {
                    res.end();
                },
            })
            );
        }).catch(e => {
            res.status(500).send(e);
        })
    });
}
```

As observed, this implementation assumes that the proxy returns json, thus the json body parser

Answer (score -2):

I think you should use `cors npm`

```
const app = express();
const cors = require('cors');
var corsOptions = {
    origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
    optionsSuccessStatus: 200 // some legacy browsers (IE11, various SmartTVs) choke on 204
}
app.use(cors(corsOptions));
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors