# Piping remote file in ExpressJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I would like to read a remote image and display it. I can save the file but not getting the code right to display it. Ideally I just want to pass the file right though without processing - not sure if a tmp file step is required or not. This code displays nothing - no errors. I tried res.pipe(response) as well.

```
var url = 'http://proxy.boxresizer.com/convert?resize=50x50&source=' + filename

var request = http.get(url, function(response) {

  var tmp = path.join(require('os').tmpDir(), filename);

  var outstream = require('fs').createWriteStream(tmp);

  response.pipe(outstream);
  response.on('end', function() {
    res.set('Content-Type', 'image/jpg');
      res.pipe(outstream);
      res.end();
  });
});
```

Comment: Where do you see `express` here?

Comment: Its the content of an express handler- i have the 'res' for the response callback. Relevant because of how Express may handle things w headers etc

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Well I'd still like to know how to make the above work but I solved my issue in one line with the [request](https://github.com/mikeal/request) module!

```
var url = 'http://proxy.boxresizer.com/convert?resize=50x50&source=' + filename
require('request').get(url).pipe(res);  // res being Express response
```

Comment: This is much better. You are not saving the file on disk. If you want to save the response, after `response.pipe(outstream);` you have to reopen the file with `createreadstream` and pipe it to `res`. In the question you did `res.pipe(outstream);` which is a mistake. You have to pipe file to `res`.

Comment: could you please share the whole code? Do you still need to end the response or any additional action?

Answer (score 11):

Since `request` is deprecated, you can alternatively use `node-fetch` like so:

```
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    fetch(actualUrl).then(actual => {
        actual.headers.forEach((v, n) => res.setHeader(n, v));
        actual.body.pipe(res);
    });
});
```

Comment: Hmm, it doesn't work for me, or at least, Typescript gives an error that there's no pipe() method.  I tried pipeTo() instead but its argument is a WritableStream not a Response object like res.

Comment: Seems to be working okay [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/node-meea3q?file=app.ts&view=editor). `actual.body` may be null so a nullish coalescing operator before the call to `pipe` may be needed, depending on your TS config.

Comment: You're right, it does work when using node-fetch, but only because node-fetch deviates from the fetch() standard.  It's documented in https://github.com/node-fetch/node-fetch#bodybody.   The standard method is pipeTo() not pipe() but it's not a 1-1 replacement.

Comment: Yeah, node has its own stream API that predates Web Streams, and that's what `node-fetch` is using. Node introduced it's own implementation of `fetch` in v17.5 and it's browser compatible. It's a [global](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v18.x/api/globals.html#fetch) since v18.

Answer (score 6):

This is what seems to work for me, using the standard `fetch()` included in Node 18, which is a bit different than `node-fetch`, see github.com/node-fetch/node-fetch#bodybody:

```js
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  fetch(url).then(({ body, headers }) => {
    body.pipeTo(
      new WritableStream({
        start() {
          headers.forEach((v, n) => res.setHeader(n, v));
        },
        write(chunk) {
          res.write(chunk);
        },
        close() {
          res.end();
        },
      })
    );
  });
});
```

Comment: Perfect! It took me a long time searching to get it to work.

Comment: After a long time searching, this finally worked for me. Bonus points for not adding yet another dependency.