# How to use Node.js File System to set the src of an img tag in a browser?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, browser, pug

I am creating an html file meant to be viewed in a browser, and on the page there is a slideshow of images that plays. I would like the iterations of pictures to play through all pictures that are in a subfolder.

Optimally, I should be able to add/remove pictures from the images folder without touching the code or ever hardcoding the names of the files. I am trying to use node.js and `require('fs')` to return a list of available files from the folder, but I am completely new to node and have no idea how to call the node file from the browser. currently this is what I have:

website.html

`<script src="app.js"></script>`

app.js

```
const fs = require('fs');

const files = fs.readdir('./images', function(err, files) {
    if (err) console.log('Error: ', err);
    else console.log(files);
})
```

Running this in the browser throws the error `require is not defined`.

I have run `npm install -g browserify` in command prompt against the folder.

How can I implement my node file in such a way that the browser can access the files in the images folder?

Comment: Node runs on the server. The browser runs elsewhere.

Comment: @Dave Newton Understood; is there no way to achieve what I'm looking for?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18432779/piping-remote-file-in-expressjs

Comment: The above post may help solve your doubt

Comment: @IshanJoshi I'm not sure how that post helps in my situation. I need a way to read from a folder and find out the names of all files within that folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### If you already know how to set up your back-end server, here's the setup using Node, Express and Pug

**Node: server.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.set('view engine', 'pug');

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

const imagesFolder = './public/images/splash';
const fs = require('fs');

var filesArr = [];

fs.readdir(imagesFolder, (err, files) => {
  files.forEach(file => {
    filesArr.push(file);
  });
});

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  console.log(filesArr);
  res.render('splash', {
    filesArr : JSON.stringify(filesArr)
  });
});
```

**Pug: splash.pug**

```
doctype html
html
  body(style='overflow:hidden')
    div#theShow(style="height:100%; width:100%; background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:center;")
    script.
      const files = JSON.parse('!{filesArr}');
    script(src='javascript/splashScreen.js')
```

**JavaScript: splashScreen.js**

```
var slideIndex = 0;
showSlides();

function showSlides(){

    var slideshow = document.getElementById('theShow');             
    slideshow.style.backgroundImage = "url('../images/splash/" + files[slideIndex] + "')";

    document.body.removeChild(slideshow);
    document.body.appendChild(slideshow);

    if (slideIndex < files.length) {
        slideIndex++;
    } else {
        slideIndex = 0;
    }
    setTimeout(showSlides, 6000);
}
```

With Node the `readdir()` funciton is used to read the directory, and the `filesArr` variable is given to the Pug file on the `get request` of the `\`, a.k.a. the root.

Pug can then access the `filesArr` variable using `!{}`. The variable `files` is set to equal `filesArr` within its own `script.` and then the external script is called and has access to `files`

It also worked out better for my use to change the `backgroundImage` of a `div` rather than the `src` of an `img`. But the javascript inside splashScreen.js could be easily rewritten to `slideshow.src = "url('../images/splash/" + files[slideIndex] + "')";` where slideshow is an `img` element instead of a `div`.

---

### If, like me you're trying to do this before understanding how to set up a back-end server for your website

There are multiple great resources on the internet about using Node, but sometimes they can be hard to find. It's even harder to find resources about how to get started for an absolute beginner.

[This YouTube video](https://youtu.be/U8XF6AFGqlc?t=560) is very informative without too much fluff and shows how to get started from nothing. (The hyperlink timestamp starts at 9:20 which is when the actual programming begins, but the first part of the video is informative as well)

After that video, the same YouTuber has a [playlist where he makes a wesbite using Node, Express and Pug](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLillGF-RfqbYRpji8t4SxUkMxfowG4Kqp) which you can watch to understand how to set up your back-end server and then you can utilize the code at the top portion of this answer!

Answer (score 0):

To list the names of all the files within a folder try:

```
fs.readdir('path-to-your-folder', (error, files) => {
    if (error) {
        console.error(error);
        return;
    }
    files.forEach(file => {
        console.log(file);
    }) 
})
```

Comment: Calling this from a browser results in `fs is not defined`

Comment: `fs` is backend module. You cannot use it in the browser. You will have to make a server side application that serves these files to your frontend

Comment: I see. I would have to, in a sense, 'push' the image on the server to the website, instead of 'pull' the image on the server from the website?

Comment: Yes, you would need to push the image from the server to the website

Comment: ExpressJs is a pretty easy way to achieve this.

Comment: If i'm not mistaken, I install Express through Node, and then when I run `npm start` it will run the JavaScript file that uses Express to push the images to the website?

Comment: Yes. This [Youtube video](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=8&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwi51_Pd1vHkAhUGPI8KHfbRCeAQwqsBMAd6BAgKEAk&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DpKd0Rpw7O48&usg=AOvVaw1nJqOb1rIwiGxvWYunZrYz) may help