# Sending streams as response of a axios request

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am making a request with an `.xlsx` file to the server, the server is generating a PDF with puppeteer, and I want to send the stream back to the client in an array to download them, but the response is not awaiting them and in the front I get an empty array.

Node.js/Reactjs

```js
router.post('/generate-payslip', async (req, res) => {
  const data = JSON.parse(req.body)
  let responsePDF = []

  data.map(async data => {
    responsePDF.push(await generatePayslipPDF(data))
    const payslips = await Payslip.findOne({ date: data.Date, name: data.Name })
    if (payslips) {
    } else {
      let payslip = new Payslip({
        date: data.Date,
        name: data.Name,
        data: data
      })
      payslip = await payslip.save()
    }

  })

  res.send(responsePDF)
})
```

Comment: Please include code samples in your question, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for more info.

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18432779/piping-remote-file-in-expressjs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wait for the mapping of `data` to finish.

Your call to [`data.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) returns a new array of promises that you can wait for using `Promise.all`.

```js
const promises = data.map(async data => {
  // ...
})

// wait for all the promises to resolve
await Promise.all(promises)

res.send(responsePDF)
```

Note, however, that this runs the map in "parallel". There is no guarantee that the PDFs are pushed to the `responsePDF` array in order.

To guarantee the order, you can return the generated PDF in the map function:

```js
const responsePDF = await Promise.all(data.map(async data => {
  // ...
  return await generatePayslipPDF(data)
}))

res.send(responsePDF)
```

Alternatively you can use a for...of loop to run it serially (one at a time). That way you do not need to use `Promise.all`.

```
for (const payslip of data) {
  responsePDF.push(await generatePayslipPDF(payslip))
  // ...
}


res.send(responsePDF)
```