# make post call to local express server in react

Tags: reactjs, express, xmlhttprequest, cors

I want to make a post call to a local express server running on port 8001 with axios in my react code like below:

```
axios.post('http://localhost:8001/enterInfo',{headers: { 'crossDomain': true }}, payload)
        .then((response) => {
            this.setState({
                saved:true
            })
        })
```

My express server is listening on port 8001. and i have written a post method in my express server:

```
app.post('/postUrl', (req, res) => {
console.log(req.body);
res.send('111');
});
```

but when i make the call from the react ui,
it is giving this error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8001/enterInfo. Response
>   to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10435407/proxy-with-express-js

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to enable **cross-origin resource sharing** on your server.

Check this [package](https://github.com/expressjs/cors) :

```
var express = require('express')
var cors = require('cors')
var app = express()

app.use(cors())

app.post('/postUrl', (req, res) => {
   console.log(req.body);
   res.send('111');
});
```