# How do I pass a Docker Compose service IP address to the front-end?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a setup similar to the following pseudo docker-compose.yml

```
services:   
  app:
    build: ./app   
  message-broker:
    build: ./message-broker
```

app is a node.js app, and I return an html file that makes a GET request to the message-broker service. So my question is:

How do I pass the hostname/IP address of the message-broker service to the front-end so that I can make a request from the node app?

Comment: You can make the request to the node app and proxy the request to the message-broker. Take a look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10435407/proxy-with-express-js

Comment: Did you get an answer to this question?  The answer below might work ok for an internal service, but I don't think works well for using from a webpage.

Comment: I followed @adebasi's suggestion. You want your server (e.g. node.js, nginx, apache, etc.) to proxy a request from your front-end to the message broker. Your web page knows how to communicate with your server, and your server knows how to resolve and proxy to every other containerized service.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `depends_on` section to your `app` service:

```
services:   
  app:
    build: ./app 
    depends_on:
    - message-broker
```

And then you can make requests to the `message-broker` service by using `http://message-broker:<port>`.

Docs: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#depends_on