# Making a proxy with request and express in node

Tags: node.js, http, proxy, request

I'm trying to make a proxy with the express and [request](https://github.com/mikeal/request) module. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7559862/proxy-with-nodejs-and-express) shows how to easily `pipe()` the request to the response:

```
app.use(express.json());       // to support JSON-encoded bodies
app.use(express.urlencoded()); // to support URL-encoded bodies
//app.use(express.multipart());

app.use('/api', function(req, res) {
  var url =proxyUrl + req.url;
  req.pipe(request(url)).pipe(res);
});
```

It works very well for all GET request. But on a POST request it fails. Can't figure out what is happening because it only runs into a timeout. The POST request works on the proxy.

What am I doing wrong? Is there any changes that I can debug the request? I have tried the following, but the file is empty:

```
req.pipe(fs.createWriteStream("test.txt"));
```

Answer (score 0):

We are also experiencing same issues, its because express.json(). After disabling json parser, it work ok. But that not the idle solution as you might need json parser.