# proxy json requests with node express

Tags: json, node.js, express, proxy

I use the following node-express code to proxy requests from a web server to an API server:

```
app.use('/api', function(req, res) {
  var url = 'http://my.domain.com/api' + req.url;
  req.pipe(request(url)).pipe(res);
});
```

This works well for simple requests of any verb (get, post, etc...), however once I send `'Content-type': 'application/json'` requests, it hangs on the `pipe` line.

**Why does this simple node-express proxy code hang on json requests?**
**How can it be altered to support them?**

Comment: Are you using a body parsing middleware before that route that is already reading all of the request data?

Comment: @mscdex I'm working on an [angular-fullstack yeoman generated project](https://www.npmjs.org/package/generator-angular-fullstack). I see the project [uses the body-parser package](https://github.com/DaftMonk/fullstack-demo/blob/master/server/config/express.js), so the answer is probably yes

Comment: Try moving your custom middleware up before the body parsing middleware (or even make it the first middleware) and see if that helps.

Comment: @mscdex thank you! commenting out [the two lines using `body-parser`](https://github.com/DaftMonk/fullstack-demo/blob/ed1578e8b82a7fae14485be6aa06419c65fa0ecc/server/config/express.js#L29-L30) did the trick, but I rather keep using it. I'm not quite sure how to "move my middleware", I set my proxy code above in [`routes.js`](https://github.com/DaftMonk/fullstack-demo/blob/ed1578e8b82a7fae14485be6aa06419c65fa0ecc/server/routes.js). Also, I think you can add your comments as an answer, I'll accept it once we solve this.

Comment: @mscdex also, can you explain why `body-parser` hangs the proxy?

Comment: "move middleware" means setting the proxy up before calling the middleware. The order in which the middlewares (proxy/bodyparser/...) are calles is essential to express. If you see it as a stack where every request goes from stackframe to stackframe, you might get an idea.

Comment: I just realized - am I using express code at all, or is this entirely a mikeal/request module question? @mscdex

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to move that custom middleware function *before* [this line](https://github.com/DaftMonk/fullstack-demo/blob/72cf7510244c577a0ed4d139cfa6fd4922ddd47d/server/app.js#L28) so that it's executed before any of the body parsers. This makes sure that the request data is still there for piping to `request(url)` in your custom middleware.

The cause of the hanging currently is that `req` has no data to write to `request(url)` (because the body parsing middleware already read all of the request data and parsed it) and so it never calls `.end()` on the `request(url)` stream. This means that the request to `url` never completes because it's just sitting there waiting for data that it will never get.

Comment: throwing an error would be better design in my eyes. I would also expect `body-parser` to only parse the data and not to extract it from `req`

Comment: Well, in order to parse the request it has to read data from the request stream. Once all the request data has been read, it's gone. With streams2 I guess you *might* be able to unshift all the data back onto the request stream, but that means you have to buffer all of that and that could be very problematic if someone uploaded a huge file for example.

Comment: two questions then: 1) does `body-parser` give access to the parsed json? and can I re-stream it into `request(url)`? 2) there's probably a reason why [routes is called after express](https://github.com/DaftMonk/fullstack-demo/blob/72cf7510244c577a0ed4d139cfa6fd4922ddd47d/server/app.js#L29), what is it? and if so should I really first proxy and only then process and then route?! shouldn't the proxy be part of the routing after local processing?

Comment: 1) `body-parser` sets its parsed result under `req.body`, so you could just `JSON.stringify()` that and write that to you outbound request. 2) Express evaluates all middleware and routes in order when a request comes in. In this particular case `config/express` merely adds a bunch of middleware (to handle body, cookie, and session parsing, static file serving, etc.) that gets executed first before any routes so that routes can get at parsed body content, etc. If your custom `/api` middleware requires a valid session for example, you will have to modify the stack order to fit your needs.

Comment: It's your suggestion 1 from your comment that worked for me. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 4):

In the case of a post request, the following construct works:

```
app.post('/api/method', (req, res) => {
  req.pipe(request.post(someUrl, { json: true, body: req.body }), { end: false }).pipe(res);
}
```

This is of course relevant if you're using the bodyparser middleware.

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for. Post some JSON, proxy it through express, return the response from the API. Excellent!

Answer (score -1):

```js
app.use('/api', function(req, res) {
  var url = 'http://my.domain.com/api' + req.url;
  
  request({
          uri: url,
          method: "POST",
          body: _body,
          json: true
      }, function (_err, _res, _resBody) {
          //do somethings
          res.json(_resBody);
      });

});
```

Comment: You should explain why your code is an improvement.