# nodejs express proxy post request

Tags: node.js, post, express, proxy, request

I want to proxy a post request, and the address of the proxy server is in post param,I have following codes:

```
app.use( bodyParser.json() );       // to support JSON-encoded bodies
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({     // to support URL-encoded bodies
      extended: true
}));
app.post('/proxy', function (req, res) {
    var proxyReq = request(req.body.url, function(err, res, body) {
        console.log(body);
    });
    proxyReq.on('response', function(proxyRes) {
        proxyRes.pipe(res);
    });
    req.pipe(proxyReq);
})
```

then I start server using

```
NODE_DEBUG=request node app
```

I use curl to send request like this:

```
curl -d 'url=http://www.google.com' http://localhost:3000/proxy
```

In server console, I can see:

```
REQUEST { uri: 'http://www.google.com', callback: [Function] }
REQUEST make request http://www.google.com/
```

But in client, nothing responses, it just hang here.
Does anyone know Why? And how to solve this. Thanks

Comment: I found the reason why it hangs here.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26121830/proxy-json-requests-with-node-express