# CORS POST request blocked in EXPRESS & REACT on hosting & domain

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I'm using express CORS module & react AXIOS on my host & domain.

I defined `CORS()` in my route middleware, and the GET request worked perfectly.

but for POST & PUT requests still, the Access-Control-Allow-Origin BLOCKED error displays.

ALSO I'm using webpack and dev server to proxy front end react

This is my express `server.js` file

```js
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

const db = require("./config/db");
db.connect(() => {
  console.log(`Postgres connected`);
});
// Middlewares

// CORS
const cors = require("cors");
app.use(cors(
    {
    origin: http://asia-sarmaye.ir
}));
// BodyParsing
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
app.use(
  bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: false
  })
);
app.use(bodyParser.json());
// Router
app.use("/api", cors(), require("./routes/dum"));

// Listening
const port = 4000;
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`);
});
```

And this is REACT axios POST request

```js
axios
          .post(
            "http://api.asia-sarmaye.ir/api/user",
            {
              headers: { "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*" }
            },
            data,
            res => {
              console.log(res.data);
            }
          )
```

any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

- You need to set proxy.
- Hope below given link help you. It helped me too.

  [Enable CORS in my React App with Node.js backend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58972357/enable-cors-in-my-react-app-with-node-js-backend)