# AngularJS CORS Access-Control-Allow-Origin errors

Tags: angularjs, cors

I try to access a different domain site that way:
http://jsfiddle.net/carolineBda/2uZnP/

I always get (error visible in the console):

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.google.fr. 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. 
Origin 'http://fiddle.jshell.net' is therefore not allowed access.
```

I've configured the httpProvider like that:

```
app.config(['$httpProvider',function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
    delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
}]);
```

Any ideas what I'm missing?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The service you are requesting is not allowing CORS (no Access-Control are sent as part of the response). So the web browser is not allowing it. This is the expected behavior and not an Angular issue.

Also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23074518)