# How to post data with Angular JS?

Tags: angularjs, cakephp-3.0

I'm trying to POST data to my application but it's simply not working. in PHP i have made some try with CURL and i don't have any issue.

**In Angular, trough the console i'm getting :**

```
Object { data: null, status: 0, headers: headersGetter/<(), config: Object, statusText: "" }
```

With Curl, i can post data with the following code :

```
# the POST data 
$email = 'test@test.fr';
$password = 'blabla';

$data = array("email" => "$email", "password" => "$password", "active" => TRUE);
$data_string = json_encode($data);

$ch = curl_init('http://localhost:8888/app/api/users/register');
# An HTTP POST request 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Accept: application/json')
);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);

//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);

//close connection
curl_close($ch);

echo $result;
```

With Angular, this code is producing the console message on the top :

```
.controller('TestCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {

  $scope.data = {};

  $scope.newUser = function() {

      $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'http://localhost:8888/app/api/users/register',
        data: {
          email:'test@test.fr',
          password:'blabla'
        },
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
        }
      }).then(function successCallback(response) {
        console.log("GREAT");
      }, function errorCallback(response) {
        console.log(response)
      });

    }

}])
```

More Information :

With CURL/PHP, the user is created and a token too.

```
string(199) "{ "success": true, "data": { "id": 18, "token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOjE4LCJleHAiOjE0NTI4NTIxODd9.vYU6YcuGS2rUUD2cBG233hSARWHp7dc1uBF7TdMrGeM" } }"
```

Header Sent trough Angular :

```
Accept :"application/json, text/plain, */*"
Content-Type :"application/json; charset=utf-8"
X-Requested-With :"XMLHttpRequest"
```

Also, i've follown this tutorial to create the Cakephp 3 api :
http://www.bravo-kernel.com/2015/04/how-to-build-a-cakephp-3-rest-api-in-minutes/

EDIT , on Chrome :

```
OPTIONS http://localhost:8888/perles/app/users/register (anonymous function) @ ionic.bundle.js:23826sendReq @ ionic.bundle.js:23645serverRequest @ ionic.bundle.js:23357processQueue @ ionic.bundle.js:27879(anonymous function) @ ionic.bundle.js:27895Scope.$eval @ ionic.bundle.js:29158Scope.$digest @ ionic.bundle.js:28969Scope.$apply @ ionic.bundle.js:29263(anonymous function) @ ionic.bundle.js:62385eventHandler @ ionic.bundle.js:16583triggerMouseEvent @ ionic.bundle.js:2948tapClick @ ionic.bundle.js:2937tapMouseUp @ ionic.bundle.js:3013
(index):1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8888/app/api/users/register. Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 500
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following:

```
var config = { headers : {'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'}};
//Stringify the JSON data
var data = JSON.stringify({email:'test@test.fr', password:'blabla', active: true});
$http.post(
      'http://localhost:8888/app/api/users/register', 
      data, 
      headers
  ).then( function(response){
         // success callback
  }).catch( function(error) {

  });
```

I prefer to separate the success and failure callbacks this way, it makes my code bit more cleaner.

Now the CORS issue, it seems your api is not allowing it, please ensure you are sending right access control headers:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

Use suggestion from one of these threads, and I hope your problem should be resolved:

- [Restangular api calls to external getting 'No Access Allowed'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23074518/restangular-api-calls-to-external-getting-no-access-allowed)
- [How to enable CORS in AngularJs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23823010/how-to-enable-cors-in-angularjs)

Remember your  server must allow these api calls, then only Angular service will be able to get data from them.

Comment: I have tried your code and the fiddle as well, i don't know what's going on, it seems that it's permission or something like that ?

Comment: It seems to be a CORS issue, i have updated my post.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a code similar to the following:

```
 $http.post("http://localhost:8888/app/api/users/register", {data: {
      email:"test@test.fr",
      password:"blabla"
    } }).success(function(){
            alert("Success!");
        });
```

I've successfully used this more "compact" syntax and it worked for me always!

Best,

Bruno

Answer (score 0):

Well, try this mode to post in angular its the best way to make a post:

CONTROLLER:

```
    .controller('TestCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {

      $scope.data = {name:'javier',age:12};

      $scope.newUser = function() {
                var peticionjson = {};
                peticionjson['name'] = $scope.data.name;
                peticionjson['age'] = $scope.data.age;
                $http.post('http://localhost:8888/app/api/users/register', peticionjson)
                    .success(function (res) {
                        console.log(res);
                    }).error(function (error) {
                    });
            }

}
```

Comment: Hi, same issue. Thanks

Comment: can you put a plunkr or jsfiddle to try it? because its the correct way to do post