# Controller is not getting call when its state is changing

Tags: angularjs

I am using ui-router for routing my angular app. I have set the routing configuration but didn't want to use controller as syntax. I am using following syntax:

```
.state('blog',{
        url: '/blog',
        templateUrl: '/templates/blog.html',
        controller: 'BlogController'
    })
```

However the template is being called into my ui-view but I BlogController is not being called. I have used console.log() into my BlogController but I didn't see anything in my console. Here is my BlogController.js

```
app.controller('BlogController', function($scope, PostService,){
    console.log(0);
    PostService.getPost().then(function(post){
        $scope.postModel = post;
    });
    console.log(1);
});
```

As you can see, I am using a service to call data using $http. Below is my PostService :

```
app.service('PostService', function ($http) {

this.getPost = function () {
   return $http({
        method : 'GET',
        url : 'http://domain.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts'
    })
    .then(function(response){
        return response.data;
    }, function(error){
        return error;
    });
};
});
```

I think this the problem related to the service call. I have read some post about resolve property in state method of ui-router. I have tried that but nothing has working. Can somebody please help me to get rid out of this ?

Comment: Please make sure if you've included BlogController.js in your main html file, and also make sure if you've registered it as a module.

Comment: I have included BlogController using require('./BlogController'). It was working fine prevously. but when I changed routing configuration from ngRoute to ui-router than it's not working.

Comment: remove the `trailing comma` in controller declaration `app.controller('BlogController', function($scope, PostService){`

Comment: what does it shows when u hit /blog in url

Comment: can you update your question including app.js settings? (as in the ui-router settings, also make sure you have included 'ui.router' in your module definition)

Comment: @Sravan is right, trailing comma is a syntax error, however if you havent seen this error then the blogcontroller file is probably not included

Comment: @Sharjil Khan, are you getting  any error in console, if yes, check my answer once, if no you haven't included the blog controller.

Comment: I am not getting an error in console. It is a typo mistake while posting this question.

Comment: @aliasav, here is my app.js                                                                      var app = angular.module('mySiteApp', [require('angular-ui-router')]);

Comment: `var app = angular.module('mySiteApp', ['ui.router'])` simply take `ui.router`

Comment: @sravan, it is working but my service is not getting any data in $http call. It is giving me a warning as : Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://domain1.com/wp-json/wp/v2/tags. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ does not match ‘http://domain2.com’). What to do in this case

Comment: just alert the response in the service and check, `alert(response.data)` before the return statement

Comment: so if your getting CORS errors, you'll need to add CORS headers from your backend, what backend are you using?

Comment: I am using wordpress as a backend. Can you pls tell me how to add CORS in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The declaration of the `ui-router module` is wrong

`var app = angular.module('mySiteApp', [require('angular-ui-router')])`

Should be,

`var app = angular.module('mySiteApp', ['ui.router'])`

[Check this link for cors errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23074518/restangular-api-calls-to-external-getting-no-access-allowed)

Comment: You're right, trailing comma is an error, however since OP hasn't seen this, the file may not have been included at all

Comment: It is a type error. I don't any error in my console.

Comment: Its adding null

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23074518/restangular-api-calls-to-external-getting-no-access-allowed